# Twisted server as production server for Django (+ django-wsgi)

Tags: django, twisted, wsgi

Is Twisted good enough to use it as q production server (+wsgi) exactly like that: http://dreid.org/2009/03/twisted-django-it-wont-burn-down-your.html/ ?
Is it a multithread and how to bind it to other IP than 127.0.0.1?

Thanks.

Comment: Here http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers Twisted shows less than stellar results for some reason.

Comment: I think that is hard to compete with modwsgi/tornado etc.. Twisted is a young project. It's very flexible, I like it. Twisted as production server it's just I need for my current project.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's multithreaded.  You can verify by checking `wsgi.multithread` key in the environment.

`twistd web` binds to *:8080 by default, so you shouldn't need to do anything else to bind to more than 127.0.0.1.

If you want to bind to something other than *:8080, then you can use the `--port` option to specify an alternate address.  For example, to listen on just the 192.168.x.x interface on my desktop, I can do this:

```
twistd web --port tcp:interface=192.168.1.148:port=8080
```

This invocation will cause the server to bind only to 192.168.1.148.

If you only have one public IP address and you just want to do name-based virtual hosting, then there's [twisted.web.vhost.NameVirtualHost](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.vhost.NameVirtualHost.html) (see the `addHost` method in particular).  There's no way to specify the vhost data on the command line though, you need to [write a .tac file](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/application.html#auto5) to configure this.

Comment: Hmm, so how to server (through twisted) two application on one machine and bind they to: domain1.com and domain2.com, available in web?